# How to use the ! operator in scala?

Tags: scala, logical-operators

I am new to scala and was trying a few basic operations to get a hang of the language.

I am trying to use the logical operators. For example :

```
 val a2 = 0x01&0xFF
 println(!a2)
```

I want to negate the value of a2 and then print it out. But it gives me an error saying

```
value unary_! is not a member of Int
```

I am not sure on how do I use the NOt operator. Could somebody help me?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? What is the result you expect ?

Comment: Like you said: `!` is a *logical* operator. But you are working with *numbers*. So, you either need to use *numerical* operators (arithmetic operators) if you want to keep working with numbers, or you need to use *logic values* (booleans) if you want to keep working with logical operators. Applying a logical operator to something which is not a logical value doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the bitwise not operator `~`.

```
val a2 = 0x01&0xFF
println(~a2)
```

Check [here for reference.](https://books.google.de/books?id=MFjNhTjeQKkC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=scala%20bitwise%20operators&source=bl&ots=FMre-MFMsp&sig=A6-TlmNgVf1qXkhI2mPsmUk9fdk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY4vW1l5jMAhUMEJoKHbefDNUQ6AEIKzAC)

Of course, this is assuming you want to negate the value bitwise, otherwise use `-`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I want to use the - to perform the not operation. But I need the answer only as a '1' or a '0'. However whenever I use this '-' operator, I always end up getting a negative value instead of a binary 0 or 1. What am I missing here?

Comment: But `a2` already is `1`. `0x01 & 0xFF` is equal to `1`. So negating it will yield in `-1` or `-2` depending on the operator used.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect to obtain -2, use the bitwise operator `~`, it will invert all the bits of your integer. If you expect to obtain -1, i.e. the opposite of your integer, use the `-` operator.

[Valid operators are listed here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Int)