# Why does using the '~' operator in scala give me a negative value

Tags: scala, logical-operators

I am new to scala and was trying to access the scala not operator. I got to know that I could use the '-' operator for  logical NOT operation. But sometimes this operator gives me a negative answer such as (-1)

For example :

```
 val x = 1
 val y =(~x)
```

Here the value y gives me a -1 instead of a 0. But I need the answer in the form of a 1 or a 0. Can somebody tell me what am I missing here ?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I'm confused: your question (title, text) refers to minus operator (`-`) but your code sample uses tilde (`~`) - which is it?

Comment: @TzachZohar Sorry. I was talking about the '~' operator.

Comment: What makes you think that `Int.unary_~` performs a logical NOT operation? The [documentation](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Int@unary_~:Long) says "Returns the **bitwise negation** of this value." [Both](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36693869/2988) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36694040/2988) to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36693811/2988) say it's a bitwise operator. Both answers link to documentation saying it's a bitwise operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike many other languages, Scala doesn't support using numbers or other kinds of values in contexts where a boolean is expected. For example, none of the following lines compile:

```
if (1) "foo" else "bar"
if ("1") "foo" else "bar"
if (List(1)) "foo" else "bar"
```

Some languages have an idea of "truthiness" that'd be used here to determine whether the condition holds, but Scala doesn't—if you want a boolean, you need to use a `Boolean`.

This means that ordinary logical negation doesn't make sense for numbers, and `~` is something completely different—it gives you bitwise negation, which isn't what you want. Instead it seems likely you want something like this:

```
val x = 1
val nonzeroX = x != 0
val y = !nonzeroX
```

I.e., you explicitly transform your number into a boolean value and then work with that using standard logical negation (`!`).

Answer (score 4):

`~` is bitwise-negation, that is it takes each bit of the given number and negates it, turning each 0-bit into a 1-bit and each 1-bit into a 0-bit. Since the first bit of a signed number denotes its sign (0 for positive numbers, 1 for negative), this causes positive numbers and zero to turn negative (and vice versa).

If you want simple logical negation, just use Booleans and `!`.

PS: Note that in the code you posted, the value of `y` will be `-2`, not `-1` as you wrote in your post.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to convert it from `0` to `1` or vice-versa you can use `^` (XOR) operator.

```
val x = 1
val y = 1^x
```